# 'Model' object has no attribute 'add' Keras Autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I wolud like to add initializer to my autoencoder

```
autoencoder=Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                bias_initializer='zeros'))
```

but I am getting this error

> 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add layers sequentially (using the `.add()` method), you need to use a `Sequential()` model like that :

```
autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                bias_initializer='zeros',input_shape=your_input_shape))
```

You can find a more complete explanation by reading the [guide to Sequential model](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) and [its counterpart for the functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will change my network for Sequential. But still I am curious- is it possible to add (using different method) initializer to Functional API?

Comment: If you are talking about the weights initialization, that's an option in the layers and thus shouldn't change whether you're using the Sequential or Functional API.